# Hive queries based on conditions

Tags: hive

Can we perform DROP TABLE/CREATE TABLE/ TRUNCATE TABLE/ ALTER TABLE IN HIVE Based on different conditions.pls help

I tried where and if clause it is not working. So want to know how we can achieve this if write this queries in hql and want to run them only if hivevar: condition = true